# YouTube Data API v3 - Problem with categoryId from category list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

If I upload a video which has CategoryId 34 (Comedy/Komödie), the API tells me the CategoryId isn't available/supported.
But I got the Categories from YouTube, saved the List in a DB with the following call:

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22hl%22%3A%22de_DE%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%7D
```

and this category exists.

So with every "failed upload" my Quota raises. Unfortunately I can upload only 6 videos a day.

Any suggestions?

I checked the Categories, still up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the URL of the request you provided in your question, you're using `de_DE` as `regionCode`.

If so, you need to use the *id* `23` instead - which corresponds to `Komödie`.

See:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
    "etag": "\"0UM_wBUsFuT6ekiIlwaHvyqc80M/l3o_qqirQJQvOVhrSz9qa3x9Nxo\"",
    "id": "23",
    "snippet": {
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
        "title": "Komödie",
        "assignable": true
    }
}
```

You can test the results in these demos:

- Results of videoCategories.list from Germany "de_DE" in [YouTube Official Documentation - "try-it" feature](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22hl%22%3A%22de_DE%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22DE%22%7D).
- Results of videoCategories.list from Germany "de_DE" in [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videoCategories.list?part=snippet&hl=de_DE&regionCode=de&fields=items%252Ckind&_h=2&).

---

If you're still sure there's a problem with YouTube Data API, my advice is search whether your problem is already reported on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) or report the problem there.